# rails way show message

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I need to display a message that the user's browser is out of date and give the user the message. The question is where to save the configuration of the user closed the message and no longer show it.

I have ideas about how to use cookies for this, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small jquery plugin. Read about it here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie